# Python function capturing subprocess stdout and stderr to log file

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, io-redirection, tee

There is a lot going on here in a small amount of code.  I'll try to keep this concise.

I have a python function that runs an external program and tees both stdout and stderr to a log file.

I'm using doctest to test the function.  I need to test the output capture functionality.  The code below shows my attempt to write the function and the test.  The test is failing with nothing written to the log file.  I'm not sure if the problem is in the test or the code under test, or perhaps both.  Suggestions?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import subprocess

def run(command_line, log_file):
    """
    # Verify stdout and stderr are both written to log file in chronological order
    >>> run("echo text to stdout; echo text to stderr 1>&2", "log")
    >>> f = open("log"); out = f.read(); f.close()
    >>> print(out.strip())
    text to stdout
    text to stderr
    """
    command_line = "set -o pipefail; " + command_line + " 2>&1 | tee " + log_file

    # Run command. Wait for command to complete. If the return code was zero then return, otherwise raise CalledProcessError
    subprocess.check_call(command_line, shell=True, executable="bash")
```

The test result:

```
$ python -m doctest testclass.py
text to stdout
text to stderr
**********************************************************************
File "testclass.py", line 10, in testclass.run
Failed example:
    print(out.strip())
Expected:
    text to stdout
    text to stderr
Got:
    <BLANKLINE>
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   3 in testclass.run
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Comment: Did you try the bash command that results from `"set -o pipefail; " + command_line + " 2>&1 | tee " + log_file` in the terminal? What does the output look like?

Comment: the text sent to the terminal is as expected with this command:   set -o pipefail; echo text to stdout; echo text to stderr 1>&2  2>&1 | tee log

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This is one small part of a large batch process generating large log files needed by users to examine the processing results.

Comment: OK I understand now :)

Comment: can you try `command_line = "(" + command_line + ") 2>&1 | tee " + log_file`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.  That worked thanks! Please make this an answer so I can accept it.  Please also explain why it works.

Comment: Oh, so are there several subcommands inside that command line, separated with a semi-colon?

Comment: @ThomasKühn yes, the test case is "echo text to stdout; echo text to stderr 1>&2"

Comment: Yes, so that's the reason then. You have two separate commands, first `echo text to stdout`, which you don't re-direct, and then `echo text to stderr`, which you re-direct  (pipe) to `tee`. If you place a pair of parentheses around the sequence of commands, you open a subshell where you execute the whole sequence of commands. The subshell itself is treated as one command by the parent shell, so now your re-direction works as you expected.

Comment: @ThomasKühn yes, what I don't get is why no output at all. Maybe because `1>&2 2>&1` chained together... well, I answered with some correct code, that works. Sometimes it's difficult to explain why broken code behaves like it does.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre see my comment to your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since doing a `subprocess.check_call` with `shell=True`, with 2 stdout/stderr redirections and a `tee` is not the best way to execute a command and capture output (actually it's closest to the *worst* way), I'm not really surprised that it fails.

My solution would be to drop the `set -o pipefail` for starters (you don't need to check return code here) and wrap both commands in parentheses else redirection / tee only applies to the last one (I'm still puzzled why you get no output al all, to be honest, though):

```
command_line = "(" + command_line + ") 2>&1 | tee " + log_file
```

And if you had to restore the `pipefail` thing, do it within parentheses:

```
command_line = "(set -o pipefail; " + command_line + ") 2>&1 | tee " + log_file
```

Comment: I think he got no output at all, because he was effectively only piping the `stderr` text to the log file, which might just have been empty.

Comment: @ThomasKühn but he was doing `echo text to stderr 1>&2`: that is supposed to issue the text to stderr.

Comment: Right, I missed that part. That's hard to test without example. Well, it's solved now ;)